# Set layout of previous view controller after device rotation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` `vc2` which is on the navigation stack after `vc1`. When I rotate the device while on `vc2`, I need `vc1` to also update its UI. However when I try and do this in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` it doesn't work.

After I pop `vc2` off of the stack, I try to update `vc1` UI in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` but it doesn't work. It works if I do it in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, but it updates the UI only after the view appears so the user can see it animating on the screen.

Is there a way to set it before the view appears so the user doesn't see the subviews animating?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem. I need to update the layout of the previous view controller on the navigation stack before it becomes visible in a custom transition.

Comment: @Sebastian Nah I still haven't. I have it in viewDidAppear currently but as states it animates after the view controller appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've found to work so far is the one I mentioned in my question where I update the UI in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. Unfortunately, you'll see your UI components animate to the proper position on screen when the view controller appears. Hopefully someone can find a better solution.